# Java- Parsing Twitter's created_at String

Tags: java, android, datetime, twitter

So I call this method:

```
System.out.println(getTwitterDate("Thu, 3 Jan 2010 18:26:07 +0000").getMonth());
```

And I keep getting `11` for every month I use.

I'm doing this in the `getTwitterDate`:

```
final String TWITTER="EEE, dd MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss ZZZZZ";
SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat(TWITTER);
return sf.parse(date);
```

I'm going by this https://stackoverflow.com/a/4522095/1193534 but removed the `sf.lenient` part.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use small y instead of Y:

```
final String TWITTER="EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZZZ";
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems to work for everything except for getYear(). I keep getting `114` instead of `2014`.

Comment: Actually, never-mind. I found out why it does that. Thanks! :)

Comment: @AdegokeA Thanks and you're welcome:-) Out of curiosity what was it?

Comment: The guy was harsh but he was right lol. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7215621/why-does-javas-date-getyear-return-111-instead-of-2011#comment8671305_7215621

Answer (score 2):

This is the latest `created_at` format received from the Twitter response for [GET lists/statuses](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/create-manage-lists/api-reference/get-lists-statuses).

`"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZZ yyyy"`